# ESP32-D0WDQ6-V3 showing "MD5 of file does not match data in flash!" message

Tags: microcontroller, arm, esp8266, esp32, esp32cam

I've designed a custom board which uses the ESP32-D0WDQ6-V3 chip, as shown in the schematic below:

[image]

Note: the pins GPIO0 and CHIP_PU are being driven by a STM32. The STM32 reads the pins of a nodemcu dev board and mirror these pins states into the GPIO0 and CHIP_PU to program the ESP32. Also, MTDI pin is intended to be low at the begining of the stm32 code.

Programming ESP32 works (sometimes), but now the problem is that through arduino IDE I got the message "MD5 of file does not match data in flash!", so it doesn't download the binary into the chip (fail).

I've tried some codes over esptool, but none manage to make me able to programe the chip. The tried commands are:

- esptool --chip esp32 --port COM9 --baud 9600 --after hard_reset erase_flash
- esptool --port COM9 write_flash_status --non-volatile 0
- esptool --no-stub --chip esp32 --port COM9 --baud 115200 --before default_reset --after hard_reset write_flash -z --flash_mode dio --flash_freq 40m --flash_size detect 0x1000 Desktop\Espressif\ESP32-WROVER-V2.4.0.0\bootloader

Please, I need a help.

**Edit**: for those who have the same problem, I've found that the external flash was the problem, the chip looked ok but it was not. So changing the external flashe solved my problem. Remember to put MTDI 'LOW' as you program the chip.